# How to rethrow an exception on a different thread than where it originated?

Tags: java, exception

I want to use two threads, lets call them *prefetcher* and *client*, the *prefetchers* job is to read an input stream *ahead* of the *client* thread and put it into some queue. The *client* then retrieves data from the queue to ... erm process it.

Now *if* the *prefetcher* encounters an exception, I need to put a pending exception into the queue, so the *client* takes an exception *when* it reaches that point in the queue.

The question is, I will have an (IO)Exception caught on the *prefetcher* thread, but I need to throw an appropiate exception on the *client* thread.

My first though is just catch it, and *rethrow* it on the other thread. But... that clearly messes up the stack trace of the exception?

So should I simply wrap it into a new exception? That would mean the "cause" is from another thread, could that cause trouble? Or must I discard the original exception completely; if somehow possible I'd like to preserve as much information as possible into the exception thrown by the *client*.

What idioms are available (and valid) to deal with this situation?

Comment: No, throwing doesn't do anything to an exception's stack trace. The stack trace is populated when you create the instance.

Comment: Just wrap it in a new exception, as cause. So the break is clear.

Comment: This pattern occurs a lot, for example parsing requests in a web service.  Generally the low-level (IOException definitely qualifies) error handling should occur at a lower level than the business logic.  If you can't do it in the prefetcher you might want to consider adding a dedicated error-handling layer in between your prefetcher and client so that the error handling is decoupled from your business logic.

Comment: I would go with wrapping the exception.  It's good to keep the original and include it in the new one for diagnostic purposes, but if you simply rethrow the original exception it will contain the wrong stack info.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I was somehow wrongly thinking that the rethrowing statement would be added to the stack trace. Turns out that was just my imagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For debugging purposes it is better wrap original exception into new one